# Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, cakephp

I get the following errors when viewing my Index

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function findAllByStateId() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/***/app/Controller/AjaxController.php on line 64
```

My code is as below

```
 public function getzone($stateid="") {
    if(!empty($stateid))  {             
        $output =array();         
        $zonelist=$this->Zone->findAllByStateId($stateid);           
        foreach($zonelist as $zdata): 
             $output[$zdata['Zone']['id']]=$zdata['Zone']['name'];             
        endforeach; 
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Any ideas what the issue is here?

Comment: how are you getting `$this->Zone`?

Comment: did you load the `Zone` model?  what version of cake are you using?

Comment: put your zone file here, check it first with isObject

Comment: if you are using cake3 (always mention your cake version) most likely is `Zones`

Answer (score 0):

**Zone** attribute seems to be null, or not a valid object,
Try to check it before accessing to **findAllByStateId()** method

```
public function getzone($stateid="") {
if(!empty($stateid))  {             
    $output = array();         
    $zone    = $this->Zone;

    if (is_null($zone) || !is_object($zone)) {
        print 'zone is not a valid object';
        return json_encode($output);
    }

    $zonelist = $zone->findAllByStateId($stateid);           

    foreach($zonelist as $zdata): 
         $output[$zdata['Zone']['id']]=$zdata['Zone']['name'];             
    endforeach; 
    echo json_encode($output);
    exit;
} 
}
```

Comment: @Halayem Anis: I think you missing `!` before `is_object($zone)`

Answer (score 0):

It means that 'Zone' should be a class that contains the findAllByStateId() function but in this instance when it tried to run findAllByStateId() zone wasn't a class so it couldn't.

The most likely cause is that whatever creates the 'Zone' instance has failed and you didn't catch the failure so when it comes to be used the program falls over.